# pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-basebackup

I'm trying to set up streaming replication between two Postgres servers. The master server's `pg_hba.conf` file is configured this way:

```
host    replication     ${REP_USER}     0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    ${DB_NAME}      ${DB_USER}      0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

And the initializer script in the slave container runs the following at startup to connect to it:

```
cat > ~/.pgpass <<EOS
${MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}:5432:${REP_USER}:${REP_PASS}
EOS
chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass

echo "Cleaning up old cluster directory"
rm -rf ${PGDATA}/*

echo "Starting base backup as replicator"
pg_basebackup -h ${MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR} -D ${PGDATA} -U ${REP_USER} -vPw
```

All the env values are set. The problem is I keep getting this error:

```
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I'm not sure why this keeps happening. I have the password file in place with the right permissions. I also have the password in the recovery file, which doesn't get created because `pg_basebackup` fails all the time.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that your [`.pgpass` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) is missing the database field, and all fields are required (although you can use it `*` for any match). As you are using `pg_basebackup` (that uses the replication protocol), you need supply that as "replication":

```
cat > ~/.pgpass <<EOS
${MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}:5432:replication:${REP_USER}:${REP_PASS}
EOS
...
```

Using `*` for the database field would work too, but `replication` is more strict.